# how to reduce the time of a nested loop in python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, web-scraping, nested-loops

I am getting the player data from ESPN, but I find myself with the problem that to get each variable the waiting time is very long, how could I improve the efficiency?

```
players_by_temp = []
for i in range(20):
    players = []
    for j in range(len(html_table[i].find_all(class_='AnchorLink'))):
        players.append(html_table[i].find_all(class_='AnchorLink')[j].text)
    players_by_temp.append(players)
    print(i)
```

Comment: First of all, you could save the result of `html_table[i].find_all(class_='AnchorLink')` in a variable instead of doing it twice.

Comment: which sport? And what exactly are you after. You likely get everything through an api. Tell me what you are after and I can show you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
players_by_temp = []
for i in range(20):
    players = []
    for anchor in html_table[i].find_all(class_='AnchorLink'):
        players.append(anchor.text)
    players_by_temp.append(players)
    print(i)
```

Once you get more comfortable in Python, you would then replace the three center lines with the following:

```
    players = [anchor.text for anchor in html_table[i].find_all(...)
```